# Can I add my own VPN to a hosted website?

Tags: vpn

I have a website hosted by a regular web hosting company.  Can I add VPN software to it?  I've read a little about hosting your own VPN but it seems to involve setting it up on your home computer.  Is that the only way to host your own VPN?

Answer (score 2):

> ... regular web hosting company. Can I add VPN software to it?

This depends on what your "regular web hosting company" (whatever this exactly is) offers. If it offers only a way to put some web pages on the internet then you cannot add some VPN software. If instead you have a dedicated server or VPS you can usually do it.

> ... it seems to involve setting it up on your home computer. Is that the only way to host your own VPN?

You set the VPN endpoint where you want the VPN endpoint to be. This might be at home in case you want to protect you are outside and want to use some Hotspot in a secure way. But this can also be somewhere on the internet (i.e. dedicated server, VPS...) in case you don't even trust your local ISP. Note that a VPN only protects the connections between your local system running the VPN software and the VPN endpoint and offers no protection after it left the VPN endpoint.